# Button and image doesnt work

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I have this button in my xaml page:

```
<Button Image="image.png" Margin="10,10,0,0" Command="{Binding ImageTo}" />
```

And this is my command in the viewmodel:

```
public ICommand ImageTo { get; private set; }

ImageTo = new Command(OnImageTo);

private void OnImageTo()
{
    CoreMethods.PushPageModel<PageModel>();
}
```

Im using the same strategy for other buttons and it works. Is there an issue with the image and button?

Comment: Did you set the BindingContext of your page?

Comment: There is no "issue" with image-based buttons and using Commands with them, as @EvZ stated, I would have to assume your binding context is not set to your ViewModel object.

Comment: No, can you show please? @EvZ

Comment: I dont have a listview @SushiHangover

Comment: @KalleP ListView? You have to assign the binding context so `{Binding ImageTo}` can be associated to the runtime object that contains the `ImageTo` property (your ViewModel as you stated in the question)

Comment: Like this? Command="{Binding ImageTo, Path=BindingContext.MyViewModel}"  @SushiHangover

Comment: Official documentation is a great place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    public ICommand ImageTo => new Command(OnImageTo);
```

you also might want to set height and width for the button.
you also have to make sure that the viewmodel is wired up.

if this doesnt work, can you tell me if there is a clickable area?

Comment: Your code will generate a new command on each access to ImageTo.

Comment: There is no clickable area but I have not set the bindingcontext. I have two listviews with bindablecontext to same viewmode (this is done)l. I need additional bindingcontext from my stacklayout to same viewmodel tho.  @Lucion